# Put and duplicate Gameobject along or accross a path Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation

I'm a beginner on Unity and I want to create a personal project, alone.
I have two Gameobjects on the Scene, I used LineRenderer and NavMesh agent on Unity to draw a path between two gameobjects, So far, everything's good, Unity draw path between two Gameobjects.

```
   Void Update (){
    OnDrawGiz(GameObject.Find("Destination"));
  }
  void OnDrawGiz(GameObject obj)
   {

    Transform target = obj.GetComponent<Transform> ();
    NavMeshAgent nav;
    LineRenderer line;
    nav= this.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    if( nav == null || nav.path == null )
        return;
    line = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.material = new Material( Shader.Find( "Sprites/Default" ) ) { color 
         = Color.yellow };

    line.startColor=Color.yellow;
    line.endColor = Color.green;

    nav.SetDestination (target.position);
    nav.isStopped=true;
    var path = nav.path;
    if (path.corners.Length < 2)
        return ;

    line.positionCount=path.corners.Length ;

    //Draw the line
    for( int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length; i++ )
    {
        line.SetPosition( i, path.corners[i] );
    }
}
```

[darw path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xIxt.png)
Now my question is how can I put and duplicate a Gameobject for example a cube along or across this path please?
 [Here photo the result which i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS8Yg.png)

I use C# script, Unity 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last `for` loop, right before or after `line.SetPosition( i, path.corners[i] );`, you can use the path.corners[i] to get the vertices along the line. Just use Instantiate there to instantiate a game object. For example:

`Instantiate(prefab, path.corners[i], Quaternion.identity);`

Check the documentation here (the first example is similar to what you want): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: I found another solution too http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1365065/put-instantiate-gameobject-along-or-accross-a-path.html?sort=votes